# GDAL Python script on dos command line opens python script

Tags: python, gdal

I want to use gdal_merge.py on the dos command line but all what happens is that the sript gdal_merge.py opens up in my python IDE (Spyder).

This happens also with with the other GDAL python scripts such as gdal_polygonize.py

Can anyone help me with this?
Cheers,
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

call it with the python interpreter:

```
c:\> python gdal_merge.py
```

If you don't write "python", Windows uses the default program associated to the .py extension (The IDE in your case)

Comment: Provided python is on your path - you can also change the file association.